# usage of --livereload command in Ionic2/ Ionic3

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionic-cli

Ionic CLI 3.8 has come up with a --livereload option to live reload the changes from your app. Can someone tell the proper command for using it?

[image]

I tried with only --livereload and also ionic cordova --livreload but neither seems to work!

Comment: `ionic cordova run android --livereload`. You can see in [Ionic cli](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/run/)

Answer (score 4):

Just like [@Duannx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4254681/duannx) mentioned in the comments, the proper CLI command is

`ionic cordova run android --livereload` / `ionic cordova run ios --livereload`

or

`ionic cordova run android --l` / `ionic cordova run ios --l`

(Or just `ionic run android/ios --l` if you're using an older version of the CLI).

Please notice that in order to make the livereload feature to work, both the device and the computer running the command **must be in the same WIFI network**.

Otherwise you'll see errors like:

> The connection to the server was unsuccessful
>   (http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX)